# Adding AWS SSL to an external DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I have bought a domain from an external resource and I tried to add the AWS SSL certificate into DNS as a CNAME record
Although the AWS Certivicate Name starts with a ' _ ' character, when I tried to add it in DNS it gives me an error as

*"Server name can be use letters hypens and dots only"*

I do not have any experience regarding this and want to know if I'm doing anything wrong in DNS Validation for AWS SSL Certificate.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options to solve this:
1. Use Email verification method to get the certificate, if you haven't enabled Privacy protection on the registrar, you'll get a verification email from AWS ACM and you can verify a certificate or ACM also sends verification emails to 5 different email addresses such as:
administrator@your_domain_name
hostmaster@your_domain_name
postmaster@your_domain_name
webmaster@your_domain_name
admin@your_domain_name

2. Use Route53, Create a HostedZone for your domain in Route53 and use the name servers Route53 provided and use it on your current registrar.
   Create and transfer all the records to Route53 , you don't need to transfer the domain, just use Route53 nameservers to your current registrar.

Comment: As the solution, I too used route 53 and got it worked. 
I think my other DNS provider restricted some of the characters of the name of the CNAME record. There should be a way to replace those characters in order to use the AWS SSL certificates in external DNS too.
Thank you for the support :)